# Where is RxJava javadoc?

Tags: rx-java

Where is RxJava Javadoc?

Hint: here is incorrect location:

http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/

Because there is no `rx.Subscriber` class indexed for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The link http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/ hosts the Javadoc of the current top version (2.x).

The version specific links are as follows:

http://reactivex.io/RxJava/1.x/javadoc/

http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/

Since there were many direct links to 1.x components, the component javadoc (but not the 1.x index) can be reached via the "rx" subpackage link:

http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html
http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observer.html

etc.